# How to change the title of a modal window?

Tags: views, 8, theming, ajax

I have a link that displays a modal window.

The link redirects to a page view.

When I click on it, it is marked in the title of the modal window `Array`.

How to customize the title ?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_agree_cgv\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the completion message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "agree_cgv",
 *   label = @Translation("Agree CGV"),
 *   default_step = "review",
 * )
 */
class AgreeCGV extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $store_name = $this->order->getStore()->getName();
    $store_id = $this->order->getStoreId();
    $pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $attributes = [
      'attributes' => [
        'class' => 'use-ajax',
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => auto,
        ]),
      ],
    ];
    $link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(
      $this->t('the general terms and conditions of the store "@store_name"', ['@store_name' => $store_name]),
      Url::fromUri("internal:/store/$store_id/cgv", $attributes)
    )->toString();
    $pane_form['cgv'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept @cgv.', ['@cgv' => $link]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: The `array` is a known Drupal Core bug, applying the latest proposed patch, as of this writting [#50](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2663316#comment-12677728), should fix it.

Answer (score 6):

mmmm if the above did not work

```
<a href="/some-thing" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:700, &quot;title&quot;:&quot;YOURTITLE&quot;}">LINK</a>
```

Comment: Or just use single quotes at first: `data-dialog-options='{"width":700, "title":"YOURTITLE"}'`

Comment: This should be marked as accepted! 